# what does lstm returns when return_state and return_sequences are false

Tags: keras, lstm

Here is my code.

```
from keras.layers import LSTM, Input
from keras.models import Model
x = Input(shape=(3,2))
lstm1 = LSTM(units=1, return_sequences=True, return_state=True)
lstm2 = LSTM(units=1, return_sequences=False, return_state=False)
out,h,c = lstm1(x)
out = lstm2(out, initial_state=[h,c])
model = Model(inputs=x, outputs=out)
```

Since both `return_state` and `return_sequences` are `False`. However, the following code still returns something. I want to understand what is that?

```
import numpy as np
y=np.array([[3,1],[2,1], 
  [1,2]]).reshape((1,3,2)) 
z=model.predict(y) 
print(z)
```

output:

```
[[-0.01467976]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [keras docs](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/)

> return_sequences: Boolean. Whether to return the last output in the
>   output sequence, or the full sequence.

setting `return_sequences=False` will return the state of the last LSTM sequence unwrapping, which in your case is of size `1`.

Change your `units=10` then you will see that it will return an array of size 10.

### Pictorial representation

[image: ![enter image description here]

- if `return_sequences=True` then vectors `y1,y2,...yn` are returned
- if `return_sequences=False` then only vector `yn` is returned

Comment: What do you mean by `state of the last LSTM sequence unwrapping`? plz give an example.

Comment: @chandresh added figure

Comment: I see. Now I understood. BTW, your input shape should be [batch_size x time_steps x input_size]